# 2 networks - 2 gateways - 2 dhcp-servers SHARE 1 print-server + 1 file-server

Tags: networking, router, routing, static-routes

I have two networks:

```
A: 192.168.0.0/24
B: 192.168.1.0/24
```

Each network has it's own gateway out to the internet and each of them as it's own DHCP-server running.
Network B want's to share it's print-server (192.168.1.199) and file-server (192.168.1.244) with the clients in network A.

How can I conntect this two networks together and set the routing rule for only accessing that two servers?

(Physically I can use a linksys (ddwrt) router which can do the routing between the two networks.)

Comment: Are there two routers or one?

Comment: there are two (= router with integrated modem). the linksys (ddwrt) could be a third one if needed to do the routing.